# Use Microsoft Graph SDK to authenticate user

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to access users' Outlook calendars from ASP Core REST API. Of course, first I need to acquire a user's access token.

I found a few steps that I need to follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?view=graph-rest-1.0) but it's based on HTTP requests that have to be performed manually. My question is, can these steps be performed with the help of Microsoft Graph C# SDK?

[I only found examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-app-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore) which required registering Azure AD in the startup.cs authentication configuration:

```
public class Startup
{
  // ...
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
  // ...
  services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
          .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration, Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[]{"user.read" })
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
   // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

Is it the only way to do it besides using HTTP client and doing it manually?

Comment: Whether you use SDK or directly make the API call, you need to follow the two step process: (1) Choose your workflow, register your app in Azure AD Identity, acquire a token which has proper scopes/permissions. (2) Use this token to call the protected resource like Microsoft Graph API, say Exchange Calendar.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SDK or directly make the API call using HTTP, just follow these steps:

- Choose your Azure AD workflow, register your app in Azure AD Identity, acquire a token which has proper scopes/permissions.
- Use this token to call the protected resource like Microsoft Graph API, say Exchange Calendar.

Here's a related [example for your view](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample), which uses Microsoft
Graph .Net SDK.